# Symfony get data from session

Tags: symfony

All session save in redis.

Me need get user id from other session.

I know session id.
How can get user id from session? If I know only session_id

thanks

Comment: We need more details. What's session ?

Answer (score 0):

In fact, if you extend the Symfony base controller, you could use a shortcut method like this:

```
$userId = $this->getUser()->getId();
```

or (Since Symfony 2.6):

```
$userId = $this->get('security.token_storage')->getToken()->getUser()->getId();
```

It's no matter what session storage you're using.

Note your `User` class should provide a getId() method when implementing `Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface`. For more details see in docs [How to Load Security Users from the Database](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/entity_provider.html).

Comment: I have some session d66gbsoond4s59gi4s6bi2vc20, pkqc5c09eg79u37jhatjb743v2, e.t.c. Me need get user_id from this session